# Issues with abcjs

Tags: javascript, abcjs

I was trying to use an example given to me in another question I asked a while ago, just changing some things here and there to learn and try to accomplish my goal. But it seems that something is not right with my ABC file.

Are there different formats for ABC files? Because the format that ABCjs is using appears to have more formatting than the format that my tablature program exports as.

Here is the example I was using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        
    </style>
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/abcjs/6.2.2/abcjs-basic-min.js" integrity="sha512-KXKtG2UKjAKEEwwKKNioYwVHGm/gH0ZmME+ePGFwbjs4Banx6+xJVtDpC2A2QM9nGtamOP4tqEYfxloLjq3XcA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="music">
X: 1
T: Cooley's
M: 4/4
L: 1/8
K: Emin
|:D2|"Em"EBBA B2 EB|\
    ~B2 AB dBAG|\
    "D"FDAD BDAD|\
    FDAD dAFD|
"Em"EBBA B2 EB|\
    B2 AB defg|\
    "D"afe^c dBAF|\
    "Em"DEFD E2:|
|:gf|"Em"eB B2 efge|\
    eB B2 gedB|\
    "D"A2 FA DAFA|\
    A2 FA defg|
"Em"eB B2 eBgB|\
    eB B2 defg|\
    "D"afe^c dBAF|\
    "Em"DEFD E2:|
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ABCJS.renderAbc("music", $("#music").text(), {
  tablature: [
    { instrument: "guitar" }
  ]
});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the ABC file I am trying to substitute in place. The ABC file below is for 5-string banjo.

```
X:1
T:No Place to Hide (AKUS Transcription)
C:Alison Krauss and Union Station
N:TablEdited by Hunter Lemon
L:1/8
Q:420
M:4/4
K:B
z[fB] F2 =A2 _B2 | [f2B2] f2 e2 =de | bf =d2 [f2B2] =A2 | [f2B2] e/f/f be =df | e2 ef be =d2 | [f2B2] f2 e2 =de | \
bf =d2 [f2B2] =A2 | [f2B2] e/f/f bf fb | =a2 [a/b/]g3/2 fe =d2 | [f2B2] f2 e2 =de | bf =d2 [f2B2] =A2 | [f2B2] e/f/f be =df | \
e2 ef be =d2 | e/f/f bf f2 e/f/f | bf fb f2 [f2b2] | f2 [f2b2] [=a2b2] [g2b2] | fe =df cB =A2 | [f2B2] b2 fb Bf | \
bB fb B2 [f2b2] | =AB Bf bB fb | Bf bB fB =A2 | [f2B2] =AB fb Bf | bB fb fB =A2 | [fB]f bg =ab [a/b/]g/b | \
fe =df cB =A2 | [f2B2] b2 fb Bf | bB fb B2 [f2b2] | =AB Bf bB fb | Bf bB fB =A2 | [f2B2] =AB fb Bf | bB fb fB Af | \
B2 AB fb Bf | B=A Bf c/=d/^d fb | [g2e2] b2 gb eg | be ce Bg =AB | F/G/f Bf bB fb | fe =df cB =A2 | =AB Bf bB fb | \
f2 =f/^f/f bf fb | fe =df cB =Af | b[fB] F2 =A2 _B2 | [f2B2] b2 fb Bf | bB fb fe =df | B2 [f2b2] c/=d/^d fd | \
=d/c3/2 Bf bB f2 | c=f c'2 bc' gb | c'=f bc' gb e2 | =f2 c'f bc' gb | c'=f b=g ^g=g ^fb | [g2e2] b2 gb eg | \
be cf Be =Af | Gf Bb Bd g2 | =f/^f/f bf fe =d2 | =A[BB] fb Bf bB | fb Bf bB fb | Bf bc =df =Af | bB F2 =A2 _B2 | \
[f4B4] fb Bf | bB fb B2 [f2b2] | =AB Bf bB fb | Bf bf cB =A2 | [f2B2] =AB fb Bf | bB fb fB =A2 | [fB]f bg =ab [a/b/]g/b | \
fe =df cB =Af | [f2B2] b2 fb Bf | bB fb Bf =AF | [f2B2] =AB fb Bf | bB fb fB =AF | =AB fb Bf bB | fb Bf bB =Af | \
[f2B2] =AB fb Bf | bB fb fB =A2 | [f4B4] fb Bf | bB fb B2 [f2b2] | =AB Bf bB fb | Bf bB fB F=A | [f2B2] =AB fb Bf | \
bB fb e/f/f b=a | fb f/b/f b=d' fb | =d'b d'b bb =a2 | [f2B2] b2 fb f2 | fb ff bf bf | fb ff bf bf | e/f/f b=a fe =d2 | \
=AB Bf bB fb | f2 =f/^f/f bf fb | f2 [=a/b/]g3/2 fe =df | B2 [f2b2] c/=d/^d fb | [g2e2] b2 gb eg | be ce Bg =AB | \
F/G/f Bf bB Gf | e/f/f b=a fe =d2 | =f/^f/f bf f2 =f/^f/f | bf fb e/f/f b=a | fe =df cB =Af | bB F2 =A2 _B2 | \
[f2B2] b2 fb Bf | bB fb fB =A_B | Bf bB fB =AF | [f2B2] d/e/b fe =dc | =A/_B/=B fb Bf bB | fb Bf bB =Af | \
=d/c/f =AB fb Bf | bf d/e/b fe =d2 | [f2B2] b2 fb Bf | bB fb fB =AF | Bf bB fB =AF | [f2B2] =f/^f/f bf fb | \
=d/c/f =AB fb Bf | bB fb fd =d2 | =f/^f/f b2 fb ff | bB =A2 =d^d fb | [g2e2] be fe =d2 | [g2e2] b2 e/f/f bf | \
fb f/b/f bb fb | f'e'2=d' bb3 | b/=d'/f'2b f'd' be' | zf'2=d'2b fb | =a/b/f ba fb bb | fe =df cB =A2 | [f2B2] b2 fb Bf | \
bB fb fB =AF | Bf bB fB =A2 | [f2B2] [=a/b/]g3/2 fe =d2 | =A/_B/=B fb Bf bB | fb Bf bB =AF | B2 e/f/b bf fb | \
[=a2b2] [a/b/]g3/2 fe =d2 | [f2B2] b2 fb Bf | bB fB fe =d2 | =A/_B/=B fb Bf bB | fb Bf bB =A2 | [f2B2] =AB fb Bf | \
bB fb Bf bf | Bf bB fB =AF | B2 [=a/b/]g3/2 fe =d2 | [f2B2] b2 fb Bf | bB fb fe =df | B2 [f2b2] c/=d/^d fd | \
=d/c3/2 Bf bB f2 | c=f c'2 bc' gb | c'=f bc' gb e2 | =f2 c'f bc' gb | c'=f b=g ^g=g ^fb | [g2e2] b2 gb Bg | \
bg cf Be =Af | Gf Bg bB f2 | e/f/f b=a fe =d2 | =A[BB] fb Bf bB | fb Bf bB =A2 | B2 =AB fb Bf | bB =A2 c/=d/^d fb | \
[g2e2] b2 gb Bg | bg cf Be =Af | Gf Bg bB f2 | e/f/f b=a fe =d2 | =A[BB] fb Bf bB | fb B=A fe =d2 | [f8B8] | \
z8 | z[fB] F2 =A2 _B2 | [f2B2] f2 e2 =de | bf =d2 [f2B2] =A2 | [f2B2] e/f/f be =df | e2 ef be =d2 | [f2B2] f2 e2 =de | \
bf =d2 [f2B2] =AF | b2 e/f/b bf bb | =d'2 [b2b2] fe =d2 | [f2B2] f2 e2 =de | bf =d2 [f2B2] =A2 | [f2B2] e/f/f be =df | \
e2 ef be f2 | =f/^f/f bf f2 =f/^f/f | bf fb bb =ab | bf =ab fb eb | fe =d2 [f4B4] | z8 | \
%:Created with TablEdit https://tabledit.com/
```

My main goal for now is to get this working properly, but soon I want to figure out a way to link an external ABC file without copying and pasting it into the HTML file.